# How can I consecutively number only some pages of a document?

Tags: page-numbering, counters

The following code typesets a 12 page document; text only appears on every other page and there's an empty page between two text pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifodd\c@page
    \begingroup
      \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox
      \global\AtBegShi@Discardedtrue
      \mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
    \endgroup
  \else
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Now I am trying to number sequentially the pages with text in them; with the code above pages with text are numbered 1,3,5,... but I would like them to be 1,2,3,... I did some attempts but none of them produced the desired result. How can I achieve the consecutive numbering?

The idea is to wrap this into a command that will allow to change the behaviour of the text flow inside a group: when invoked, the command will cause the text to be typeset in every other page but maintaining the consecutive numbering for the pages with text; once the  group ends the text and numbering must return to their normal behaviour.

Comment: What is an odd page?  The third absolute page would have page number two.

Comment: I do not recommend explcitly or implicitly calling `\shipout` inside `\AtBeginShipout`.
An empty page can output by `\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null` (absolute page counters have
to be corrected manually). `\clearpage` might even add further float pages.

Comment: In the shipout routine the page and therefore its page number is known, `\label` based approaches like `\checkoddpage` are not needed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks for your comments; I quite don't understand the second one... this is the first time I am trying to do something with the shipout mechanism and I am kind of lost. Where am I calling `\shipout` inside `\AtBeginShipout`? Why don't you recommend doing so?

Comment: The shipout routine is called by the asynchronous output routine, in the middle of shipout the example adds material to the main vertical list and calls `\clearpage`. Thus it can happen that in the middle of shipping out a page material is added somewhere later and the output routine is called again and might want to ship out a page while shipping out a previous page. A mess already. `atbegshi` is not reentrant, one of the reasons are possible global assignments of the shipout box.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ah, I see. So basically all I had to do was `\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}

\AtBeginShipout{
    \ifodd\value{abspage}
    \else
      \stepcounter{abspage}
      \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null
    \fi
}`. Would you like to write an answer, perhaps turning your comments into answer? Now I have a much better understanding of what's going on. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me. The trick is to use a different counter for the number of shipouts
instead of the pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{mypage}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipoutInit{\setcounter{mypage}{0}}
\AtBeginShipout{
  \ifnumodd{\value{mypage}}{
    \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  }{
    \mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
  }
  \addtocounter{mypage}{1}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

First page \pageref{test}
Last page \pageref{test2}

\label{test}
\lipsum[1-30]
\label{test2}

\end{document}
```